# Is it possible to have a widget which is constantly updating?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app that will take updating text (from a twitter feed) and make it scroll like a billboard sign as a homescreen widget. I am aware of the battery hit, but I am wondering if it is even possible to have a widget which is constantly pulling from a source. What are your thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure it's possible.  Lots of widgets do this.  Are you having problems with implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your content is represented in separate strings (and not in any sort of stream), one way of doing this would be to run a separate Thread, or use a Handler with postDelayed Runnable, which would execute an AsyncTask, which would fetch your string from the desired URL at specific timeout.

Also, how about using sockets? You could be receiving your strings exactly when they are updated, not wasting the battery that much.

Comment: interesting approach, I will have to do some research on sockets but that could be a good solution.

Comment: I used [socket.io](http://socket.io/) in one of my projects, check it out. [Mavenized lib on GitHub](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java)